# Marriage post-marriage?

Tags: halacha, marriage, niddah

I have a question.

I was civilly married, and now I want to do a kosher Chuppa.

However, my rabbi said that the chuppa cannot be a chuppas niddah? Why not? It's not a second wedding or anything?

Please help me understand this issue.

Comment: Not everyone thinks chupas niddah is ever ok. Do you know this is related to your civil ceremony?

Comment: @DoubleAA, it seems to me that you could post an answer that speculates that the rabbi was simply holding like the "not everyone," if you document and explain that.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is since she is not a Besulah (virgin) Chuppah does not acquire the woman, it is the actual living together (ביאה) or being secluded together in a way that they could've been together (יחוד הראוי לביאה).
Now, it is permissible to get married in such a manner but they are not allowed to be secluded without witnesses.
See Shulchan Aruch Horav Siman 339:8 and Mishna Berurah #32.
My assumption is that the Rabbi doesn't want to startup with your feelings of being married yet you can't sleep in the same room (and/or house), he preferred to keep you 'unmarried' until you can 'benefit' from being married.
In any case, Mazal Tov!